# Android JSONException: Value API cals quota exceeded

Tags: android, arrays, json, api, jsonexception

I just ran into this problem today where I'm trying to get values from a json file. This problem even appeared for an old fully tested build. I've also never seen this before so has anyone had any experience with this? Is there a way to resolve it?

Full Error:

```
10-16 01:38:10.449 9300-10047/com.andrewxia.carnanny W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value API calls quota exceeded! maximum admitted 60 per hour of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
10-16 01:38:10.450 9300-10047/com.andrewxia.carnanny W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
10-16 01:38:10.450 9300-10047/com.andrewxia.carnanny W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
10-16 01:38:10.450 9300-10047/com.andrewxia.carnanny W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
10-16 01:38:10.450 9300-10047/com.andrewxia.carnanny W/System.err:     at com.andrewxia.carnanny.business.BusinessLayer.processLotResponse(BusinessLayer.java:73)
10-16 01:38:10.450 9300-10047/com.andrewxia.carnanny W/System.err:     at com.andrewxia.carnanny.business.BusinessLayer.getParkingLots(BusinessLayer.java:34)
10-16 01:38:10.450 9300-10047/com.andrewxia.carnanny W/System.err:     at com.andrewxia.carnanny.views.MapsActivity.getAllParkingSpots(MapsActivity.java:174)
10-16 01:38:10.450 9300-10047/com.andrewxia.carnanny W/System.err:     at com.andrewxia.carnanny.views.MapsActivity_.access$301(MapsActivity_.java:30)
10-16 01:38:10.450 9300-10047/com.andrewxia.carnanny W/System.err:     at com.andrewxia.carnanny.views.MapsActivity_$4.execute(MapsActivity_.java:132)
10-16 01:38:10.450 9300-10047/com.andrewxia.carnanny W/System.err:     at org.androidannotations.api.BackgroundExecutor$Task.run(BackgroundExecutor.java:405)
10-16 01:38:10.450 9300-10047/com.andrewxia.carnanny W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
10-16 01:38:10.450 9300-10047/com.andrewxia.carnanny W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-16 01:38:10.450 9300-10047/com.andrewxia.carnanny W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:154)
10-16 01:38:10.450 9300-10047/com.andrewxia.carnanny W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
10-16 01:38:10.450 9300-10047/com.andrewxia.carnanny W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
10-16 01:38:10.451 9300-10047/com.andrewxia.carnanny W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
10-16 01:38:10.451 9300-10047/com.andrewxia.carnanny W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party API that has quotas to how many calls you can make per day?

Comment: Wow, I realized I'm dumb, I misread that error and thought there was an api limit to the json call which was why I was so confused. Ignore me, I'm just tired. BTW: thanks dude.

Comment: No worries. Been there too. Take a break and continue your work later when you're more refreshed. :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON call wasn't throwing the limit error, the api I was using was throwing that error. Just too tired for this.